# apache vs lighttpd vs nginX as OpenLayers / GIS Server

Tags: openlayers-2, web-service, server

How is using one of the above technologies to host an Openlayers-based GIS application?
My investigation with apache and lighttpd showed that apache is not the best for heavy load environments.

In some cases there have been suggestions to try out the ngin-X route. Has anyone tried the three against each other and made a benchmark or a test?

Thanks!

Comment: The fact that your using OpenLayers is irrelevant to the load of the server because OpenLayers is Javascript and all the load happens on the browser. I believe your question is more like which servers perform better in heavy load environment? This might be a better question at StackOverflow or ServerFault. Otherwise you might want to tell us about the technologies that openlayers will be calling on the back end.

Comment: yeah. Sure I just left the question a bit open to see what other people are doing and using.
Mainly my backend technology is PHP5 maybe with a framework...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When unsure follow the leader:

http://news.netcraft.com/archives/2011/11/07/november-2011-web-server-survey.html

and remember to write your app as agnostic as possible from one particular piece of technology.

Among all the choices that you will have to make (like: which gis server, which php framework, database or linux version, etc) I feel that the web server is the least important.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PHP5, use Apache and mod_php. Only switch when you need to - spending time on this decision isn't very useful unless the site's going to get 100k visitors on the first day.